# Is this a good idea to implement inject before and after advice in javascript?

Tags: javascript, aop

```
var myfn = function(arg){
    var be,af,_fn;
    setTimeout(function(){
      be && be();
      console.log(arg);
      af && af();
    });
    function bef(cb){be=cb;return _fn;}
    function aft(cb){af = cb;return _fn;}
    _fn = {
       before: bef,
       after: aft
    }
  return _fn;
} 
myfn(1).before(function(){console.log(0);}).after(function(){console.log(2);})//0 1 2
```

It works quite very well,but dont know what the issues are??
I see many AOP's implement  just wrap myfn and return a proxy fn,such as jquery AOP plugin.

Comment: What function do you wrap here, `setTimeout`?

Comment: Why did you make the decision not to return a proxy function?

Comment: Regarding the `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

The main issues I see here are

- your function does not `return` anything
- you always need to know the argument before you add the before/after callbacks
- your function is not generic, it does not wrap arbitrary functions

Comment: That's right,my demo can only eval a function but return nothing.I now understand setTimeout's disadvantage :)